# How we can manage the accounts with multiple chains on substrate?

Tags: account

I need to do the transaction from the multiple chains(Eth, Solana, etc) on the substrate How can we manage the accounts with that interoperability of the chain?
Do we have any solution for that Interoperable problem in Substrate?
Please share some ideas if someone has any idea about this.

Comment: What exactly is the use case? Ethereum and Solana are two different blockchains that are not (yet) parachains. Are you hoping to somehow control accounts on Ethereum from substrate?

Comment: Yeah, I am hoping to somehow control accounts on Ethereum from the substrate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To **control** another network's account (or in fact any account), what you really need is a wallet - which could be implemented as a portal like Moonbeam
or polkadot.js/apps does it, or as an extension like Metamask - and such a wallet needs to support both networks.

Of course a wallet in itself doens't help much, if there is no way to transfer your tokens from chain X to a substrate chain. What you need is some kind of a bridge, ideally a trustless one (e.g. the Snowfork bridge that's in developlment to connect to Ethereum), so that the wallet can make requests, over such a bridge, to transfer the tokens to the other network.

In terms of UX, you could probably find inspiration from how Moonbeam does it - since it's an EVM chain, they use Metamask on a custom network as a wallet (so your tokens are held in an EVM-style address), but thanks to cross-chain transfers, you can send these tokens to some parachains to your substrate address (e.g. to Acala).

You can think of the Moonbeam parachain as the equivalent of Ethereum network (also EVM based), and the cross-chain messaging, broadly, as the messasges passed over the Snowfork bridge (though the part of the bridge that's on substrate will most likely need to be a parachain itself, so cross-chain messaging will be involved too).